# unable to install pulse aduio

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio

I accidentally removed pulseaudio using "sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio" and now i am unable to reinstall it.

audio on my computer is mot working anymore.
please help i have my project demonstration tomorrow.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3) but 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
              Recommends: pulseaudio-module-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

Revert to an older version of libpulse0 with:

```sh
sudo apt install libpulse0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3
```

then re-install pulseaudio with:

```sh
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```